# How to store data from foreach loop into variables? Fetching data from multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql

i want to store data into my database. I can output the in table form but can not store in variable  to access later. I don't think I explain it clearly but hope you can get the idea what I would like to express.

I'm using php and mysql

```
<?php
    $data = file_get_contents('https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?status=processing&consumer_key=ck_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&consumer_secret=cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
        $data = json_decode($data, true);  
?>
    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    <?php foreach ( $data as $row ) : ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?= $i; ?></td>
        <td ><?= $row['number']; ?></td>
        <td ><?= $row['billing']['first_name']; ?> </td>
        <td><?= $row['billing']['last_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['date_created']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['status']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['billing']['email']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['total']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['shipping']['address_1']; ?></td>


    </tr>
    <br>


    
    <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

[Data in frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ucJe.png)

Answer (score 0):

The question needs a little more detail and more code to fully explain what you are doing. However, based on a bit of guesswork, this might help you. Simply move the record set into an array:

```
$result_array=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    $result_array[] = $row;
}
```

The resulting array can be accessed multiple ways. A simple example is:

```
$result_array[0]['column_name'];
```

Comment: hello sir I am fetching the data from WordPress rest API on my website and want to store in localhost mysql database. The code working fine but can't store the data into variables for later sending into the database.

Comment: code updated please check now